# Error executing Cypher exception on session.save()

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using neo4j-ogm 2.0.0.M5 with neo4j 2.3.3 and trying to save an annotated POJO.

After calling session.save() I get an exception: 
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher

The cypher statement(autogenerated by neo4j-ogm) which fails is as follows:

```
UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`PatientSummary`:`Summary`:`List_`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId
```

I am not quite sure what is wrong here. Any tips on how to proceed?

thanks!

Comment: What is the CypherException code and description? Can you also turn debug on  <logger name="org.neo4j.ogm" level="debug" /> and check what params are passed to it?

Comment: @luanne, here you go:  
  
**CypherException Details**    
  
`code=Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidType
description=Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof`

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it's trying to save a property that isn't a valid type- what does your pojo look like?

Comment: It is pretty complex. These are business objects that we are trying to save.  Not designed for OGM from scratch. Is that the recommended approach? If the property value is another object that needs its own node, how do we do that?

Comment: Then you need a relationship to that property. See the short tutorial here: http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/